# Creating a HttpClient in node.js in Thrift

Tags: python, node.js, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am using thrift for cross platform integration. I have a python server in thrift.

**Python Server**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

port = 30303
host = '127.0.0.1'
import sys
sys.path.append('gen-py')

from helloworld import HelloWorld
from helloworld.ttypes import *

from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.transport import THttpClient
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from thrift.protocol import TJSONProtocol
from thrift.server import TServer
from thrift.server import THttpServer

import socket

class HelloWorldHandler:
  def __init__(self):
    self.log = {}

  def sayHello(self):
    print "sayHello()"
    return "say hello from " + socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())    

handler = HelloWorldHandler()
processor = HelloWorld.Processor(handler)
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(host=host, port=port)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()
#pfactory = TJSONProtocol.TJSONProtocolFactory()

#server = THttpServer.THttpServer(processor, (host, port), pfactory)
server = TServer.TSimpleServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

print "Starting python server..."
server.serve()
print "done!"
```

I created a node client in thrift which is able to access the python server when a TSimpleServer is created in python, but fails to connect when a THttpServer is created

**Node client**

```
var thrift = require('thrift');
var ThriftTransports = require('./node_modules/thrift/lib/thrift/transport.js');
var ThriftProtocols = require('./node_modules/thrift/lib/thrift/protocol.js');

var Calculator = require('./gen-nodejs/HelloWorld.js');    
    ttypes = require('./gen-nodejs/helloworld_types.js');    

transport = ThriftTransports.TBufferedTransport()
//protocol = ThriftProtocols.TJSONProtocol()
protocol = ThriftProtocols.TBinaryProtocol()

var connection = thrift.createConnection('127.0.0.1', 30303, {
  transport : transport,
  protocol : protocol
});

connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("error in connection");
  console.error(err);
});

connection.on('connect', function(){    
    var client = thrift.createClient(Calculator,connection);

client.sayHello(function(err, response) {
  console.log(response);
  connection.end();
});
})
```

I made sure I used JSON protocol when running the THttpServer in python.
I am unaware of how to create a HttpClient for node in thrift.

Sorry for dumping the code, but I thought it will make the question clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Node http client support was added on April 23, 2014. The library support is only in the dev branch at the moment but will be released with 0.9.2 at some point in the not too distant future. Here's a sample client for a service called heloSvc using the http node connection/client:

```
var thrift = require('thrift');
var helloSvc = require('./gen-nodejs/helloSvc.js');

var options = {
   transport: thrift.TBufferedTransport,
   protocol: thrift.TJSONProtocol,
   path: "/hello",
   headers: {"Connection": "close"}
};

var connection = thrift.createHttpConnection("localhost", 9090, options);
var client = thrift.createHttpClient(helloSvc, connection);

client.getMessage("Thurston Howell", function(error, result) {
  console.log("Msg from server: " + result);
});
```

Comment: thx fr saving my googling time codeSF :)
Hoping for a patch soon

Comment: but I just checked, there is one made already a patch I guess:  
[link](http://grokbase.com/t/thrift/dev/138thb0dm7/jira-commented-thrift-1893-http-json-server-client-for-node-js). I just dont know how to use it yet

Comment: Saw your note on the dev list. Hope one of the contributors gets the patch in for you. It is a needed feature for sure.

Comment: I just committed a node http client, there's a test in thrift/lib/nodejs/test/http_client.js, ping the dev list if you need a better example

Comment: You can find an example node.js http client, node.js http server and python http server here: https://github.com/RandyAbernethy/ThriftBook/tree/master/part3/nodejs